# Add a Time column to Devise and have it updated manually from controller in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a need to see when an user started a subscription. I need to add a new column named `subscription_started_time` in the `users` table created by a Devise generated migration.

I can easily add the column, but how do I populate it? I obviously shouldn't use strong parameters, because the time input will be added straight from the controller and it wont be coming through a form.

What would be the best way to handle input straight from Ruby when the user creates/updates an account?

Comment: Wouldn't just simple setting an attribute of a user, and saving it be enough? `user = User.find(1)` `user.update_attribute(:subscription_started_time, Date.new)` ?

Comment: Where should I be adding this? Do I need to override the Registration Controller?

Comment: Should the `subscription_started_time` be set once `User` is created (eg. when registering)?

Comment: Yes, I want that to happen when the user registers for the first time (or updates his subscription, but this one is something I can handle)

Comment: Ok then - please, check my answer. It's the cleanest way of doing so - I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set `User`'s `:subscription_started_time` at it's creation, you can use one of `ActiveRecord`s hooks - `before_create`.

Let's consider an example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  before_create do
    self.subscription_started_time = DateTime.new
  end
end
```

Please, check [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks) for more hooks available for your `ActiveRecord` models.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'll give this a shot and report back to you.